# Why can't I ssh using a port other than 22 with macOS 10.15.4?

Tags: macos, catalina, ssh

I'm trying to ssh to a machine that opens the port 8012 for ssh as opposed to port 22. When I ssh at the command line (`ssh -p 8012 username@host`), nothing happens. The `-vvv` option gives no pertinent information other than "trying to connect".

I can do `ssh ssh://new@sdf.org` (on standard port 22) without problems.

Further, on this Mac I have a VM running Debian. *Within this VM I can ssh on the machine with the non-standard port 8012 without problems.*

I also have a separate Windows machine where I also have no problems doing what I described.

Edit: output of `ssh -vvv ...`:

```
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [destination] port 8012.
```

And then it gets stuck there.

Output of `cat ~/.ssh/config`:

```
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Uncommented lines of the output of `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

Comment: Assuming you’re not  trying to do port forwarding since it’s working on Ubuntu, did you reconfigure `sshd_config` to listen on port 8012?

Comment: @Allan I don't control the ssh serving machine.

Comment: If it’s not configured to listen on that port, it’s not going to connect.  Did you configure the port in Ubuntu or is it too, something you don’t have control over?

Comment: @Allan Are you talking about the server or my computers? The server is perfectly fine and hundreds of people are connecting to it. I just can't conenct to it from my Mac but I can from a VM within the Mac and from another machine running Windows. My question is really "how can I analyze and debug my problem since it's clearly something wrong with the Mac?"

Comment: Then your descriptions are unclear then.  Re: the Ubuntu machine on your a Mac... is `ssh` working from the Mac (host) to the Ubuntu guest or are you saying the Ubuntu guest can connect to that server with “hundreds of people” connecting using the non-standard port?

Comment: @Allan The server is some business computer that is not mine. I'm trying to ssh to it. The Linux guest can connect to that server using the non-standard port. My Windows machine can connect to it using the non-standard port. The Mac cannot.

Comment: Do you have a firewall running?

Comment: @Allan The Mac's own firewall is on, yes but turning it off doesn't help.

Comment: When you use the `-vvv` option, you're getting all diagnostic  info.  "Trying to connect" means it can't make the connection.  Specifically when it's off, do you get any more info from the console using the `-vvv` flag?  Can you ping the server?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I can ping the server. I've added the output of `ssh -vvv` command and contents of the config files.

Comment: Are you running 10.15.4 by chance? See https://mjtsai.com/blog/2020/03/31/macos-10-15-4-broke-ssh/, there are some potential workarounds in the comments there. If one of them works for you, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @nohillside Yes. And, thanks, I've found the answer there. Specifying the IP address fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears my issue is specifically tied to a recent update of MacOS. The answer was found here: https://mjtsai.com/blog/2020/03/31/macos-10-15-4-broke-ssh/. Specifying the IP address of the server rather than its name resolved my issue.